# Locating defects from Jira Xray using Graphql

Tags: graphql, jira, jira-xray

I am trying to use Graphql to export test cases and their execution results for any test case in a specific Test Plan.  I was able to write the Graphql script to get all the details from the test execution I need, but the one problem is that the defect value returned is a string of numbers rather than the actual defect key.   I tried using jira fields in the code for "links" and "linked issues", but that didn't work.   Does anyone know how to just get the specific defect key associated with the test case?  Here is my code:

```
{
    getTestExecutions(jql: "key = Demo-123", limit: 100 start:0) {
        results{
          jira(fields: ["key", "summary"])
    
          testRuns(limit: 100 start: 0){
              total
            results{
                test{
                  jira(fields: ["key", "summary", "description"])  
                }
              status{
                name
              }
              comment
              defects
              

              steps {
                  status{
                    name
                  }
                  action
                  result
                  actualResult     
                  customFields {
                   value
                    }
                    defects
                                  
              }
              
            }
        }

    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To obtain the issue keys of the defects, currently you need to invoke Jira's [REST API](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/rest/v3/api-group-issues/#api-rest-api-3-issue-issueidorkey-get) for that.

`GET /rest/api/3/issue/{issueIdOrKey}`

You need to do this for every issueId that is returned on the `defects` object of the test run object returned in the GraphQL request.

Here's a code snippet for achieving that, in Python:

```py
import requests
import json
import os
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

jira_base_url = "https://yoursite.atlassian.net/rest/api/3"
jira_username = client_id = os.getenv('JIRA_USERNAME', "xxxx")
jira_password = os.getenv('JIRA_PASSWORD',"xxx") # password is actually an API token obtained from https://id.atlassian.com/manage-profile/security/api-tokens




def getIssueKeys(issueIds):
    issueKeys = []
    for issueId in issueIds:
        # endpoint doc https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/rest/v3/api-group-issues/#api-rest-api-3-issue-issueidorkey-get
        response = requests.get(f'{jira_base_url}/issue/{issueId}', params={}, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(jira_username, jira_password))
        res = response.json()
        issueKeys.append(res["key"])
    return issueKeys


issueIds = ["12933", "12933"]

print(getIssueKeys(issueIds))
```

Note: Xray's GraphQL API doesn't yet (as of Oct2022) provide a primitive/function for that.